# pandas.concat and bad/corrupt data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am using pd.concat to concat 15,000+ CSV files. Some of the CSV files have bad (corrupted?) data, which I do not want.

**The code I am using to concat:**

```
for filename in files:
    try:
        df1 = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0, error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=True, quotechar=None, quoting=3, sep = ' ', skiprows=1, lineterminator='\n', engine='c', encoding='utf-8')
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        df1 = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0, error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=True, quotechar=None, quoting=3, sep = ' ', skiprows=1, lineterminator='\n', engine='c', encoding='cp1252')

li.append(df1)

data = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True, join='inner')
```

The code shown above works, and I am able to concat all of the files. However, the output CSV now contains some bad data which is causing problems for me (column data types are being changed to an object). Essentially though, even though I use error_bad_lines=False, my CSV files still contain bad data.

**Example of a csv which contains good data and bad data:**

```
1554309123 03-APR-2019 17:32:03    0.0    0.0  292.4    0  307.6     0.0     0.0   40    0.0    0     0.0     0.0    0.0
1554309841 03-APR-2019 17:44:01    0.0    0.0  292.4    0  307.6     0.0     0.0   40    0.0    0     0.0     0.0    0.0
1554309911 03-APR-2019 17:45:11    0.0    0.0  292.4    0  307.6     0.0     0.0   40    0.0    0     0.0     0.0    0.0
1554309911 03-APR-2019 17:45:11    0.0    0.0  292.4    0  307.6     0.0     0.0   40    0.0    0     0.0     0.0    0.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    [šê;C®ÃtkïÎÒ««¹sÛI‹sÀÂ’¿†­ï0TÆÞ²¾ÝÙ¡êž¡ÛÎìío2ã¼XA¿&FÍä=€+Z>Žö6¿œ:½Y.5:õÖl›WFøM¦Z¦ÓY‡*Ýêåêïàa×.ªþÛs ãßEŽßØ»rûú‡ËÆzøa6[8Ù:HWw/çUÄõ†^`BHdê<&ži„ñ‡tòPXÞ€êáÆ6Ò‡ÀÁ£Œ3ÒX£7â˜£Ž;òØ£?¤CY¤‘G"™¤’žt–—x«‘e ‡ûýæQw%¦Ý‹PŽ¥Õxahšgí-9ˆ
W÷•u`n8X‚þ­gÑTÖéÆ[•¢Qùå™    &6Ð‰eÊñsIkJ±×Ó‰dútÔUkV)SFçX*N(æ^å*QƒºèèiýÙi^”¨_T.˜U”vQ~jféÒ‡¦^Úé²É êdþ>Zá¢m¢pZiÅº%ÝœLÌÙ"› -Å›ºöqY
|]„l¶¸&„“œK×‚Èµê%‰´rV¯Ç f ÔÆ¡.Å"{j¥ÂêÛ€1X9+§ø¾Kâ»)Üª‹¶}ë¼sìI_röå»‚~êåeñYåT,íÇ¨p,VÌàÂy€ëä¦Bê×”aŽ9°‚:)¬æ–årLq«Ç<jËiÜ³Ï?´ÐC]´ÑG#´ÒK3Ý´ÓOCµÔSS]µÕWcµÖ[sÝµ×_ƒ¶Øc“]¶Ùg£¶Úk³Ý¶ÛoÃ·ÜsÓ]·Ýwã·Þ{óÝ·ß¸àƒ^¸á‡#ž¸âA†  ;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ¨Ê2Bð“;Ì¤¥XÌc"ó~­då0u'H?^Ž–Elß%A¹KQ®íš²œä©yÊeÂxÚŒ%9Ë   M‚S˜Üæ\ÙÍ®™ëÌÝ[yHJ›°Übüú¸È:‚’†–¦>Ï˜þÎpø3“‘\§#ÑÈÄ}æR¡˜üaO§Iu2¡ôŒ&‹ùÃ‰RÔœñœgH%§D‚fÓ‹E&.›©·—´¥¬¥A]ºRµÁ’q*E  sZIlž-ˆ6­¨ !*ÐmÊ´…Ó%QßÇÊ{"5©c<$L5jÐ£ö´žd§MHÁ™Öò•LYËjÖ³¢5­j]+[ÛêÖ·Â5®r+]ëj×»âu£Ó¬j(C:¿J•©Þ,¨XCIÒ”Ž5°\ê5#ÊÓ<¢3¦yíG¹¨Î’Þ4—9íª1«ZÍ_Š1«ƒ<lfXRÐž¶›?¬7²ºE‚q“3e$AF¯Êð‹¼(UiGþÛU…ö„êH¯zÏ­ö´‘¬mmb9[È6ÎŒ£ågA5˜<ÝŠ–©i#ƒ[\õ§&½`b
«ÜåF¥œÃî6òÍj:–§ÔÅ'ç ©Â«Jwªj{Ï©ÈBš7¾èÍY~C‡Òñ®Rž~}Å|iZ9ÃÖšÁ\­.LNäz‘“ç
ðVLàM
```

So that bad data is being concat into the other CSV. This is causing issues because the dataframe is being changed from a column type int/float64 to object. In order for me to work on the data, I need to keep it as its intended data type, but obviously the bad data is being concat in and the column is being changed to an object data type.

If the bad data were simply all 'Null/NaN' I know I could resolve this issue. However some of the bad data is technically normal (the bad data contains a mixture of NULL, weird unicode, letters, numbers etc) and is therefore not being skipped by error_bad_lines=False

Question 1: Is there a way for me to delete rows of data which do not have a specified delimiter? I believe this would be a really good solution.

Question 2: Another solution, however not as suitable, due to the fact that there is GOOD data in the problematic CSV files. I am using GLOB to load all of the CSV files. Perhaps there is a way for me to code it so that glob skips files which contain bad/corrupted data?

EDIT:

```
data.dropna(inplace=True)
```

This drops most of the NULL values, but not strings. There is still bad data in string format in columns which should only contain int/float

Answer (score 0):

I'd really dig into the arguments to [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html). They're your friend here. Specifically:

> - `dtypeType` name or dict of column -> type, optional
>   Data type for data or columns. E.g. `{‘a’: np.float64, ‘b’: np.int32, ‘c’: ‘Int64’}` Use str or object together with suitable na_values settings to preserve and not interpret dtype. If converters are specified, they will be applied INSTEAD of dtype conversion.
> - `usecols` list-like or callable, optional
>   Return a subset of the columns. If list-like, all elements must either be positional (i.e. integer indices into the document columns) or strings that correspond to column names provided either by the user in names or inferred from the document header row(s). For example, a valid list-like usecols parameter would be `[0, 1, 2]` or `['foo', 'bar', 'baz']`. Element order is ignored, so `usecols=[0, 1]` is the same as [1, 0]. To instantiate a DataFrame from data with element order preserved use `pd.read_csv(data, usecols=['foo', 'bar'])[['foo', 'bar']]` for columns in `['foo', 'bar']` order or `pd.read_csv(data, usecols=['foo', 'bar'])[['bar', 'foo']]` for `['bar', 'foo']` order.
>
>   If callable, the callable function will be evaluated against the column names, returning names where the callable function evaluates to `True`. An example of a valid callable argument would be `lambda x: x.upper()` in `['AAA', 'BBB', 'DDD']`. Using this parameter results in much faster parsing time and lower memory usage.

These can be used in combination to enforce data types and column names you expect to see in each file. If you provide the exact columns you expect to see with `usecols`, and a certain file is missing columns or isn't readible, you'll get a ValueError. If you indicate a type for one of your columns and a value doesn't match, you'll get a TypeError. You can then handle these gracefully.